# Split string by keeping "-" in words while eliminating it in other places in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to split this string `str = "hello, ,, one-word. yes - no: yea?"` into

```
String[] parts = [hello, one-word, yes, no, yea]
```

So far, I have used `str.split("(\\p{Punct}*\\s)+"))` which gives `parts = [hello, one, word, yes, no, yea]`, and `str.split("[\\p{Punct}&&[^-]]*\\s"))` which gives `parts = [hello, one, -, word, yes, -, no, yea]`.

How do I split the `str`, keeping the `-`s and `_`s in words but eliminating them and other regex in other places? I also want to eliminate cases of multiple punctuation and white space, such as `.,    , ,`.

Comment: make sure that `-` and `_` are surrounded by letters. Something in the likes of `[a-zA-Z]*-[a-zA-Z]* || [a-zA-Z]*_[a-zA-Z]*`

Comment: Try `\\s+[_-]\\s+|[\\p{Punct}_&&[^-]]*\\s`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can `split` using this regex in Java:

```
"\\s+-\\s+|(?:(?!-)[\\s\\p{Punct}])+"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wM6rD0/1)

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/7PXk4y)

Comment: Could you tell me how you came up with the answer? @anubhava

Comment: Since you didn't want split on `-` surrounded by non-space chars I used them first in alternation. Then `(?!-)` is negative lookahead, needed to skip `-` in punctuation chars

Answer (score 2):

```
    String str = "hello, ,, one-word. yes - no: yea?";

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
        str.split("(\\p{Punct}(?!\\w)|\\s)+")
    ));
```

This will give you `[hello, one-word, yes, no, yea]`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of splitting the string you can find all the words with following regex:

```
"(?=\w)[-\w]+"
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, my String is not in English so your regex will omit some of the characters. For example, your code will make the String `H\u1ecdc` become `Hc`. Any other idea?